# Find table cell based on changing lookup value

Tags: jquery, search, html-table

I'm trying to create some script to find the value of a table cell based on a select field (level) then multiply that value by a free text field (hours). To get a total.

I can get this to work with two free text fields, but I am stumped on how to get it to work with a select field

Here's the basic table:

```
<table id="myTable">
  <thead>
    <th>Level</th>
    <th>Rates</th>

  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>level 1</td>
      <td>25</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>level 2</td>
      <td>30</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>level 3</td>
      <td>35</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Then here's the input fields:

```
<input type="text" id="hours">
<select id="rates">
    <option>level 1</option>
    <option>level 2</option>
    <option>level 3</option>
   </select>
   <p>Total <span>zero</span></p>
```

Then this is my script:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {

        function search( key ) {
        return $('td')
          .filter(function() {
            return $(this).text() == key;
          })
          .closest('tr')
          .find('td')
          .eq(1)
          .text();
      }
      var rate = document.getElementById('rate');
        $(rate).on('click', function() {
        var value = search($(this).val()) || 'zero';
        var hours = document.getElementById('hours').value;
        var Total = parseInt(value)*parseInt(hours);
        $('p').find('span').text(Total);

      });
    });
```

While I can get this code to work if #rates is a free text field, I can't figure out how to get it to work on a select field.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess you miss the 's' char on the ID of select.

```
var rate = document.getElementById('rate');
```

that should be like

```
var rate = document.getElementById('rates');
```

and you can use on("change") rather than use a click event, so after the value is changed you can get the value.

```js
var rate = document.getElementById('rates');
$(rate).on('change', function() {
  var value = search($(this).val()) || 'zero';
  var hours = document.getElementById('hours').value;
  var Total = parseInt(value)*parseInt(hours);
  $('p').find('span').text(Total);
});
```